# How to know that Google API must be used during project import?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

As far as I see, an indicator that we must use Google API during the project import still does not exist in Android Studio. I still have to use my own logic or visual indicators to know that I must set Google API as the project's API.

I usually realize that I have to use this API instead of the regular SDK if:

1. I see that Google services are used (maps or similar)
2. The app does not want to start and logcat does not report anything (crashes on start without any logcat error in the console)

Is there a better way to know during project import that we have to use Google API SDK instead of the regular Android SDK?

Comment: There aren't two SDKs. Are you talking about Google vs. non-Google AVDs in the emulator?

Comment: @ScottBarta Sorry, I meant Google API. I used SDK word where it should not be used.

Comment: Local project done by someone else in the past

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can see is if you look at the **app** file (aka the build.gradle file in the app folder) under dependencies, if it has `compile 'com.google...` in it, like the below code, it will need the Google API.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

**Edit**

For any project, including non-gradle, you can also look at the AndroidManifest.xml file and search for

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

For google API services to run properly, it will need to know the version code, so that will likely be found in all projects needing Google APIs.

Comment: In case of Gradle-based project, it's easier. What about in non-Gradle-based project (like old Eclipse)?